# What is the latest behavior of "console.log" regarding its latency in execution, across the popular browsers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console, console.log

I was experimenting with JavaScript and I ended up with this snippet:

```
var num = new Number(20);

function f(n) {
n["foo"] = "bar";   
} 

// the printed object has a "foo" property.
console.log(num, f(num));
```

I never thought the printed object would have the `foo` property added to it in the `f(num)` call, because `f(num)` comes after the `num` in my `console.log` (I am using Chrome).

But that happened and my immediate thought was that `console.log` was sort of running all the arguments and printing out the results or something, so I went over to MDN's documentation for `console.log`, but there wasn't anything about that.

Then I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138248/google-chrome-console-log-out-of-sequence) StackOverflow question.

The second and third questions say that `console.log` is a little late when used with objects, but in that case, the printed object in the following snippet should have had a `foo` property as well (since it is a `Number` object), it doesn't:

```
var num = new Number(20);

function f(n) {
n["foo"] = "bar";   
} 

// no "foo" property
console.log(num);
f(num);
```

The accepted answer to the question I mentioned pretty much says what the second and third answer say, except, it also states that the behavior is console or browser dependent. So, how do different browsers treat this sort of thing nowadays (that question is from 6 years ago) ? Is `console.log` asynchronous for extremely large objects only ? And the original question, why does the `num` in my first example get printed out with a `foo` property ?

Comment: Apparently `console.log()` is "sort-of" asynchronous in Chrome. Similar issue occurred the other day: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046935

Comment: That question hasn't been answered either, it is sort of demoralizing. But, if it is asynchronous, then when is it asynchronous ? As I have shown in the second example, it is not asynchronous where it is supposed to be (according to an answer to a question I linked to).

Comment: @Taurus It's not really asynchronous, but inspecting objects might be done asynchronously. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392650/1048572) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// the printed object has a "foo" property.
console.log(num, f(num));
```

This behavior is not specific to `console.log`. All of the arguments to a function are evaluated (in order) before the function starts running. Since `f(num)` is an argument to `console.log`, it is called before `console.log` gets a chance to look at `num`.

In essence, what's going on is:

```
var arg1 = num;
var arg2 = f(num); // modifies num in place, so arg1 changes as well
console.log(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Great! It is thid subtle and important pieces of information that I am after. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it feels really natural, I wouldn't have been confused if I were thinking of "console.log" as a normal function. Actually, it is a longer story than that as well.